# Android how to access Fragment Adapter in Activity? (Adapter is null)

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, fragment

I have Activity(BottomBar) - Fragment(RecyclerView) - FragmentAdapter(RecyclerView Adapter)

1. RecyclerView show list.
2. bottomBar visible when I clicked item one of the list.
3. I clicked item in bottomBar(ex.delete)
   -> I want to access FragmentAdapter and notify item delete or something
   --> but when I call FragmentAdapter, it is null

**Activity**

```
ListFragment listFragment;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listFragment = new ListFragment();
        ...
}

bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
    (BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener) item -> {
         switch (item.getItemId()) {
             case R.id.delete:             
             listFragment.delete();
             return true;
         }
});
```

**Fragment**

```
public void delete(){      
   fileListAdapter.delete();   // it is null
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Event Bus call the event you need adapter

second viewbinder you can use for share activity fragments data

3rd you can make static adapter and call it everywhere in activities
static Adapter adapter;

Comment: Thanks. I solved a problem using Event Bus(otto).